# Magento: Change Swiss B2B Customer to specific Magento Customer Group

Tags: php, magento, configuration, magento-1.9

I need a solution to change the customer group of customers with a default shipping address in Swiss or Norway. We have multiple store views. One of this is the b2b store view. I need a solution only for this store view. Is there a way to define this via Magento Tax Configuration?

I tried to solve this over the event trigger `<customer_save_before>` but at this point I can't get data from new saved shipping addresses.

Update - what i've tried so far:

```
public function customerSaveBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    /* @var $customer Mage_Customer_Model_Customer */
    $customer  = $observer->getCustomer();

    if($customer->getPrimaryShippingAddress()) {
        $adress = $customer->getDefaultShippingAddress()->getCountryId();
        if (Mage::helper('core')->isCountryInEU($adress) === TRUE && $customer->getGroupId() == "5") {
            $customer->setGroupId('3');

        }
        elseif (Mage::helper('core')->isCountryInEU($adress) === FALSE && $customer->getGroupId() == "3") {
            $customer->setGroupId('5');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.